# What does「打ってなかった」mean here?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Someone (Aさん) asks a question on a forum. Bさん provides an answer. I see the answer as incomplete, so I correct Bさん and provide some supplementary information. Aさん, the OP, replies to me:

> あ、本当だ。完全に見落としてました。ありがとうございます‼️

I thought that was the end of it. But then Bさん says back to me:

> 打ってなかった

I am thrown by this response. I don't know what Bさん is trying to say or if they are displeased because I corrected them (not the first time). What does 打つ mean here? "It didn't occur to me"? What's also off about that response is everybody is very polite on the forum, basically 敬語 all the way. Bさん too, except in this one repsonse to me.　えっため口？なんで？俺、何か悪いことした？ That's how I feel. So what do they mean?

A little more background: it is a math question. The correct answer includes two possibilities, and Bさん only gives a number based on one of the possibilities. I complement their answer by showing another possible option.

Comment: 「打つ」は "type" だと思うんですけど、、 もうちょっと文脈がほしいかな。。

Comment: @Chocolate I added a little more context. Since it is not an open forum, I can't really link the discussion thread or include a screenshot... This is probably the best I can do. Sorry.

Comment: Objectively the context is still not enough, plus the line is too short, so it's open to many many possibilities you should suspect before thinking he's displeased, such as: self-reflection, posted immaturely, partial correction/insertion to previous comment, etc etc. Perhaps you can reply it with a single 「？」 that means you didn't get it.

Comment: @EddieKal That's a good piece of information not only cleared my hidden prejudice but also provides a new pragmatic context: that line may sound blunt if used by a male speaker, but much more likely to be used to lightly put her thought by a female speaker. It also suggests it is she that 打ってなかった.

Comment: @brokenlaptop Lol just as I removed my last comment--I felt I was giving away too much personal information about that person. It makes sense now. Thanks!